# Is it more common to say 他写汉字写得好 Or 他的汉字写得好?

Tags: grammar, usage, difference

I wasn't able to find a similar question, its a bit pedantic but I would like to know if one is more common than the other in spoken or written language. According to my Chinese teacher, both are correct, just wondering if one is more 'local'.

Comment: Both are fine. But IMO, "很好" should be used instead of just "好".

Answer (score 1):

Now that other answers mention that 很 must be added, I’ll briefly comment on it.

If added, 很 is used as a linking particle, lost the meaning of very to some degree. It gives a feeling of completion. But without 很, they’re still perfectly ok sentences, though *it suggests that the speaker might have more to say, or invites the listener to continue the conversation*.

---

Sure these two are both correct, but the second one is much more natural. Also, they mean slightly different things.

**写汉字写得好** is best used as a non-predicate loose structure, Verbal Phrase + Complement. E.g., 如何形容写汉字写得好？ 如何形容打篮球打得好？

The second best is to use it attributively, like 写汉字写得好的人。But in this case first 写 is more redundant than above. A better way is to say 汉字写得好的人, without changing any of the implication. The Chinese language prefer two-syllable feet, so if the verb phrase is comprised of two syllables only, then the repeated verb is OK, like in 写字写得好的人. On the other hand, since Chinese was historically single-syllable-dominated, for many scenarios in Modern Chinese single syllable is still good, like in 字写得好的人, which is equally good as the previous one and has exactly the same implication (though structurally a bit different).

The worst application is to use it as a verb predicate, as in 他写汉字写得好. For the same reason, a better is to say 他写字写得好/他字写得好 or 他汉字写得好. Among native speakers, 字 by itself refers to 汉字. For example, 你字写得这么好，为什么英语写得那么难看？ 字 by default refers to 汉字, so the sentence has no logical problem. The first two are used among native speakers while the third is used to compliment a Chinese learner. These being said, the first has a different structure and focal point than the other two.

In 他写字写得好, 写得好 is the complement for the preceding verb predicate 写字. So it says that he can perform the action of writing Chinese characters to a good degree. In 他（汉）字写得好, 他 is the topic, while （汉）字写得好 comments on the topic. So it says as for him, Chinese characters can be written well.

他的汉字写得好 is perfectly "local", similar to the above-mentioned, to compliment on a Chinese learner. Here the topic is 他的汉字 while 写得好 is the comment. To compliment a native speaker, 他的字写得好 is used.

In terms of "locality", saying to a Chinese learner, 他的汉字写得好 = 他汉字写得好 >>> 他写汉字写得好. If the scenario is clear, say the speaker is watching someone writing, then 他的字写得好 = 他字写得好 = 他写字写得好 are all good.

Saying to a native speaker, 他的字写得好 = 他字写得好 = 他写字写得好 >>> 他的汉字写得好 = 他汉字写得好 >>> 他写汉字写得好.

I don't see noticeable difference in the written form. Perhaps among all the colloquially natural forms, 他字写得好 is slightly not as natural, but still good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in both sentences we Chinese will add 很 before 好。

他写汉字写得好 ----  他写汉字写得很好。

他的汉字写得好 ----  他的汉字写得很好.

他的汉字写得很好。 We use this structure more in both spoken and written languages.